# I'm trying to create a string with n characters by allocating memories with malloc, but I have a problem

Tags: string, malloc, fgets

```c
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    
    int main(void)
    {
        int n;
        printf("Length? ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        getchar();
        char* str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (n+1));
        fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%c\n", str[i]);
        free(str);
    }
```

Process results like this!

Length? 5
abcde
a
b
c

?

(I wanted to upload the result image, but I got rejected since I didn't have 10 reputations)

I can't figure out why 'd' and 'e' won't be showing in the results.
What is the problem with my code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(wellcome to stackoverflow :) (update #1)

`str` is a *pointer to char* instead of a *character array* therefore `sizeof(str)` is always `8` on 64-bit or `4` on 32-bit machines, no matter how much space you have allocated.

Demo (compilation succeeds only if X in static_assert(X) holds):

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

  // Pointer to char
  char *str=(char*)malloc(1024);

#if defined _WIN64 || defined __x86_64__ || defined _____LP64_____
  static_assert(sizeof(str)==8);
#else
  static_assert(sizeof(str)==4);
#endif

  free(str);

  // Character array
  char arr[1024];
  static_assert(sizeof(arr)==1024);

  return 0;

}
```

[fgets(char *str, int num, FILE *stream)](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) reads until (num-1) characters have been read

Instead of `fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin)` please `fgets(str,n+1,stdin)`

Fixed version:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  int n=0;
  printf("Length? ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  getchar();
  char *str=(char*)calloc((n+1),sizeof(char));
  static_assert(
    sizeof(str)==sizeof(char*) && (
      sizeof(str)==4 || // 32-bit machine
      sizeof(str)==8    // 64-bit machine
    )
  );
  fgets(str,n+1,stdin);
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    printf("%c\n",str[i]);
  free(str);
  str=NULL;
}
```

```
Length? 5
abcde
a
b
c
d
e
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. It helped a lot (:

Comment: @DanielCha You might want to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)